# Cannot read property 'event' of undefined FullCalandar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

https://jsfiddle.net/studovey/jvrwfzea/21/

[image]

[image]

Im getting the following error in FullCalendar.js every time I select Day view I get this error.  There is an event on the below date so it throws the error.

I thought that it could be something to do with the formatting perhaps.  I have looked online for solution but to no avail.

Can anyone share any throughts?

My code is the following:

```
    function GetAppointments() {
        var initialLocaleCode = 'en';
        $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            buttonText: {
                today: 'Today',
                month: 'Month',
                week: 'Week',
                day: 'Day'
            },
            footer: true,
            selectable: true,
            height: 650,
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAppointmentData", "Admin")',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    selectable: true,
                    locale: 'en',
                    titleFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var events = [];
                        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
       var start = data.start;
                            var end = data.end;
                            events.push({
                                eventID: data.Id,
                                title: data.title,
                                description: data.description,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                backgroundColor: data.type.TypeColour,
                                textColor: 'white',
                                borderColor: 'white',
                                allDay: false,
                            });
                        });
                        callback(events);
                    }
                })
            },

            nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00',
            editable: true,
            droppale: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            eventClick: function (info) {
                GetEventDetailByEventId(info);
            }
        });
        $(".fc-day-header").addClass("bg-success");
        $(".fc-day-header").css("color", "white");
        $(".fc-button, .fc-agendaWeek-button, .fc-state-hover").addClass("bg-success");


    }
```

```
        // Grab individual elements from the combined HTML string. Use each as the default rendering.
            // Then, compute the 'el' for each segment. An el might be null if the eventRender callback returned false.
            $(html).each(function (i, node) {
                var seg = segs[i];
                var el = view.resolveEventEl(seg.event, $(node));

                if (el) {
                    el.data('fc-seg', seg); // used by handlers
                    seg.el = el;
                    renderedSegs.push(seg);
                }
            });
        }

    function GetEventDetailByEventId(eventinfo) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAppointmentById", "Admin")',
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'id': eventinfo.id
            }),

            success: function (data) {
                $('#appointmentHeader').removeClass('bg-success');
                $('#appointmentHeader').addClass('bg-info');
                $('#btnUpdate').removeClass('d-none');
                $('#btnDelete').removeClass('d-none');
                 $('#btnAdd').addClass('d-none');
                $('#headerText').html('Update Appointment');
                $('#btnBackAdd').removeClass('d-none');
                $('#txtTitle').val(data.Name);
                $('#txtName').val(data.Info);
                $('#txtStartDate').val(moment(data.StartTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"));
                $('#txtEndDate').val(moment(data.EndTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"));
                $('#hdnAppointmentId').val(data.Id);
                $('#drptype').val(data.type.Id);

            }
        })


    }
```

Comment: It's probably not related to your issue, but FYI `selectable: true,
                    locale: 'en',
                    titleFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",` are not AJAX options, they're fullCalendar options. I think you've put them in the wrong place.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, it isn't but it is a start thankyou

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of this code like a js fiddle ?

Comment: What is the code in 4641? Also can you share GetEventDetailByEventId(info) this function

Comment: hi @FerhatBAŞ I have now shared those in the original screenshot

Comment: Where did come segs "var seg = segs[i];
                var el = view.resolveEventEl(seg.event, $(node));" did you checked that it has a value. Please check vua console log

Comment: its in the fullcalander.js file

Comment: @AlwaysHelping https://jsfiddle.net/studovey/jvrwfzea/20/

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether you are getting the expected values for `data.StartTime` and `data.EndTime` that you are passing into the function? The error `event of undefined` might be coming from `moment`. I faced that once.

Comment: Hi Chintan, i have shared a screen shot of my console.log in the original post it looks like the correct start date is being pulled through.  Thanks for your input

Comment: There does seem to be an issue here, if i change start to hard coded: moment("2020-09-30 15:30:25").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),  it works, if i change back to data.StartTime i get the error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the value of data.StartTime and put the console.log statement right above the statement with moment. See if you're getting the expected value there. It should help you get closer to the cause of the issue.

Comment: Also, the screenshot that you added to the question - it has different property names than the one you are accessing.
For eg, the screenshot has properties like `title`, `start`, `end` whereas in the code you are trying to access `data.StartTime`.
Is that conversion working as expected? The issue could be lurking there as well.

Comment: Hi Chintan, thanks for your response, i have change those while digging for errors and just updated the original post.  start and end are pulling through as "start":"2020-09-04 09:45:00","end":"2020-09-04 12:45:00".  When i type it in hard coded it works when its Json it doesnt.

Comment: $(html).each(function (i, node) {
     var seg = segs[i];
     //console.log('node' + JSON.stringify(node));
     //console.log('seg' + JSON.stringify(seg));
     var el = view.resolveEventEl(seg.event, $(node));

     if (el) {
      el.data('fc-seg', seg); // used by handlers
      seg.el = el;
      renderedSegs.push(seg);
     }
    });

Comment: Above is the problem, when it gets to day few from the HTML its not getting the 'seg'.

Comment: Hi @Stu did you found a solution? I need to fix a legacy project that is failing in the same "seg" variable.